# Error: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. MLPClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Trying my hands on MLPClassifier. Am I doing the right thing?

Below is my code:

Earlier I wrote:

```
x =[[181,80,44],[177,70,43],[160,60,30],[154,54,37],
   [166,65,40],[190,90,47],[175,64,39],[177,60,43],
   [171,57,44],[191,85,42],[165,55,40]]
```

But I'm trying to reduce my code as follows:

```
x =[(np.random.randn(36).reshape(12,3)).tolist()]

y= ['male','female','female','female','female','male',
   'male','female','male','female','male','female']
clf = MLPClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(x,y)
prediction = clf.predict([[0,0,0]])
print(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by this line:

```
x =[(np.random.randn(36).reshape(12,3)).tolist()]
```

Here you've created an array with 12 rows and 3 columns, which is just fine for use as features for a classifier, and then you turn it into a set of 12 lists of 3 items using `tolist()`, which is not necessary. Then you have a list comprehension `[]` around that, which creates a list of 12 lists of 3 items each, when all you really needed was a 12x3 array object like you initially created with `reshape()`.

Use the following line instead and that error will go away:

```
x = np.random.randn(36).reshape(12,3)
```

I will add that you are using a very small training set, with both classes randomly generated from the same distribution. This will not allow for a good separation since they're essentially the same data split up randomly between two arbitrary classifications of `male` and `female`.

You should instead randomly sample two different distributions (different mean and stdev) and use a higher sample size for training and testing if you're going to create your own dataset. I recommend trying some of the [sklearn datasets](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#toy-datasets) or looking up some tutorials to get a better idea of what I mean.